# Cassandra, Design user liked item table

Tags: database-design, cassandra, database, nosql

I have a list of items, I'd like to know if current user has *liked* some of them. I'm wondering how to design my table as it's the first one I'm doing in C*. So I want to know if I'm heading towards the right direction :

I was thinking about having userID as primary key and item liked as clustering column.

The problem I see with this is that if an user likes so much things the partition won't fit on a node (so I lose the data ?). I have no idea how many item an user has to like for that to happen but my guess is that it's not even doable for a human. The thing is that the eventuality is still there and it bothers me. Also what if there is already a lot of data on a node, does it mean the amount of item an user has to *like* is lower in order for the partition to be too big for a node (since there is less available memory)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement is correct when you say that all the data will be in a single node and if there is insufficient space on that node the write will fail. If you worried about this you could also add something like a "timestamp" or "bucket" column to your primary key in order to reduce the size of you partition.

Cassandra has a hard limitation of 2 billion cells per partition but in practical terms I believe that the advice is to keep a partition <100 MB in Cassandra 2.0 and earlier and <200-300 MB in Cassandra 2.1 and later.  If I were you I would do a bit of a calculation to see how many items a person would need to like in order to get near these limits and decide if this is a limitation you are willing to accept.  You can get a good description how to do that [here](https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds220-data-modeling/physical-partition-size).